# How can I automatically refresh expired Google Calendar API tokens in Python?

Tags: python, calendar, token, google-calendar-api, refresh

I'm using Google Calendar API to make my program in Python.
So I make a JSON file from the Google API dashboard.
After a week later, the token is expired so I Google about it.
I found:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

def get_credentials():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return creds
```

This code is from Google, so I use it,
but it doesn't work. Downloaded a new JSON from the Google API dashboard or do something doesn't work.

```
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})
```

How can I solve this problem?
I want to make it automatically using code.

I searched about this problem in Google and found code about this problem but it doesn't work.